# Heroku CI Timeout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, procfile

I am having a problem with Heroku CI on a rails application.  I just upgraded to Rails 7.0.1

Previous version was Rails 6.1.4.4

```
# Ferrum::TimeoutError:
     #   Timed out waiting for response. It's possible that this happened because something took a very long time (for example a page load was slow). If so, setting the :timeout option to a higher value might help.
```

This is how my Procfile looks like

```
  web: bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb
  release: bundle exec rails db:migrate
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you're receiving this error because the `:timeout` parameter is missing in the Dynos. Try to create a Procfile and pas a `:timeout` var.

You can find some more useful help right here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/request-timeout